# Does the size, and distance between, expanding ultracold gas clouds depend on the populations in each cloud?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fermions, cold-atoms

Say you had some $^{87}$Rb atoms at a few kelvin and you knew that the atoms were
distributed among the magnetic sub-levels of a hyperfine manifold. You want to know the relative population of each by use of a linear magnetic field gradient. Does the population of each of the states determine the size of the clouds and the distances between them during the expansion?

I'm thinking that the interactions between the atoms will make the states with more atoms larger but the distance between the expanding cloud centers should be the same?